# Como filtrar pelo método? Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Preciso filtrar todas as imagem que possuem um link específico, consegui fazer o filtro através do `status` da tabela produto, porém o que liga a imagem ao produto é o método `image();` da classe `Produto`:

Método `image()` da classe Produto:

```
public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ProdutoImage', 'erp_productid', 'erp_productid');
}
```

Preciso pegar o valor `erp_image` do `ProdutoImage` e passar para o filtro tentei fazer dessa maneira, mas não filtra:

```
if(request()->has('erp_image'))
{
    $produtos = Produtos::where('erp_image', request('erp_image'))
              ->paginate(25)
              ->appends('erp_image', request('erp_image'));
} 
else 
{
    $produtos = Produtos::paginate(25);
}
```

Na minha `View` adicionei o `Link`:

```
<a href="/products/?erp_image=http://teste.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/produtos/teste.jpg">
    <span class="label label-primary">Sem Imagem</span>
</a>
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Não deu pra entender direito, mas seria isto?

```
Produtos::whereHas('image', function ($query){
    $query->where('erp_image', request('erp_image'));
})->paginate();
```

Retorna os produtos que tem uma imagem que satisfaz o filtro.